# Is there a way to automatically refresh data in workshop

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I have an application showing an object location on a map. The underlying data is refreshed every minute or so. Is it possible to make workshop refresh the data and update the position automatically every minute?

Answer (score 0):

> You can enable Auto-refresh within a specific Workshop module. Navigate to the Auto-refresh configuration options toward the bottom of the Settings panel in the Workshop editor.

https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/workshop/auto-refresh/